# sendSubviewToBack on iOS not working

Tags: ios, storyboard, uicollectionview

I am trying to move a storyboard created UIImageView called pic behind a programmatically created collection view. However, the collectionView is first moved back behind some buttons. Unfortunately, the collection view ends up behind the pic. And yes, I have also tried to delay it by a few seconds and it still won't work.

```
  [self.view sendSubviewToBack: collectionView];
        [self.viewsendSubviewToBack: pic];
```

***Update***
I have determined that it is because the storyboard created UIImageView called pic is refusing to go all the way to the back. How do I send that to the very back?

Comment: Probably worth noting that if `pic` is a subview of `collectionView`, then it can't be sent behind the collection view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have determined that it is because the storyboard created UIImageView called pic is refusing to go all the way to the back. How do I send that to the very back?

We don't know much about your app's view hierarchy, but you may try

```
[[self.view superView] addSubView: pic];
[[self.view superView] sendSubviewToBack: pic];
```

or

```
[[self.view superView] insertSubview:pic belowSubview:self.view];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    [self.view insertView:pic atIndex:0];
```

this will ensure pic is under everything.. you might have to revisit the exact index depending on what else is in your view and what their sizes are and if the order is changing..